# Can I embed the Simulink interface in a MATLAB GUI?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, drag-and-drop, simulink

I would to display the Simulink workspace in a MATLAB GUI window.  This is
cosmetic as I know well that Simulink operates fine without this addition.

However, I have no idea how to have a space in a GUI where the Simulink
workspace can be displayed.  Effectively, the GUI would form a thick frame
around the Simulink workspace.  Please let me know how what commands can be used to create the workspace window.

Also, is it possible to have a place to store a reservoir of blocks, similar to the Simulink
library, in this GUI.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Simulink workspace" - do you mean the Simulink block diagram editor? (If so, I don't believe you can put that in a MATLAB figure)

Comment: Yeah the block diagram editor is exactly what I am referring to. Ahhh I really hope I can.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB GUIs and the Simulink editor rely on incompatible technology.  You will not be able to embed the Simulink editor into a MATLAB GUI.  What requirement do you have for Simulink modeling that isn’t met by the editor?  There already exist many ways to customize the Simulink environment.

Answer (score 0):

Doug is right about the Simulink editor, but you do have some freedom to put your own reservoir of blocks into the Simulink library browser. There is a [section](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/brkl0a6-1.html) in the doc that describes how to do this.